# dhcp 'next-server' outside broadcast domain, without using ip helpers(aka dhcp relay)

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

Can you set a 'next-server' option in dhcp that is outside of the client's broadcast domain? I'm trying to pxe-boot from a server outside my client's network, using isc-dhcpd

In my lab I see the next-server option get sent from the dhcp server to the client, however I never see the client interact with the next-server.

I know this is possible on a switch using ip helper(bootp relay, dhcp relay, etc) but am looking to do it without using that.

Comment: This _ought_ to work, provided your first server actually served an IP address, mask and gateway. But the client may be too dumb to follow it, especially in a pre-boot environment.

Comment: my client is a macbook pro 12,1(2015-ish)

Comment: You're aware that Macs don't boot with PXE, right? Apple uses their own protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a PXE environment is perfectly doable.

in a BSDP environment (PXE for Macs) the game is different; the BDSP client broadcasts its first request and expects a list of possible booting images, the user picks one and starts the boot/install process.

in your case you will never see a BDSP client following the next-server option like a PXE client does. [BSDP documentation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/bootp/bootp-198.1/Documentation/BSDP.doc)